# String in a list returns False value

Tags: python

I am not sure why the second folder variable is not returning "True." c000nu2x is in my folderList and EqList. I was searched for "u" in lists online, but it returns type list and not unicode. Thank you for any help.

```
>>> print type(EqList)
<type 'list'>
>>> print EqList
[u'c000nu2x', u'c000ntpw']

>>> print folderList
['11199709', 'c000nu2x']

>>> for folder in folderList:
    print folder
    folder in [EqList]

11199709
False
c000nu2x
False
```

Comment: you're making EqList a list of lists.

Comment: instead of looking in this `[u'c000nu2x', u'c000ntpw']`, you're looking in this `[[u'c000nu2x', u'c000ntpw']]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You created a **nested** list:

```
folder in [EqList]
```

Remove the brackets:

```
folder in EqList
```

Your test tested if a list of one element containing the `EqList` object contained `folder`; that is always going to be false.

Demo:

```
>>> EqList = [u'c000nu2x', u'c000ntpw']
>>> folder = EqList[0]
>>> folder in [EqList]
False
>>> folder in EqList
True
>>> [EqList]
[[u'c000nu2x', u'c000ntpw']]
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 1):

`[EqList]` is a list that only contains `EqList`. You want `folder in EqList`.